# What languages other than Lua support an infinite variety of string delimiters?

Tags: syntax, language-design

`my_lua_string = [=[ This is a string delimited with long brackets; it contains other valid long brackets like [[this]] (or this: ]==]), but they are ignored because Lua looks for a long bracket that matches the opening delimiter. ]=]`

Lua supports something I haven't seen in any other language: so-called 'long brackets', sometimes also referred to as 'long strings' or 'double brackets'. There is an infinite variety of valid long bracket pairs: `[[my multiline string]]`, `[=[...]=]`, `[==[...]==]`, and so on. You can use them for multiline comments like so: `--[[...]]`, `--[=[...]=]`, etc. This means that any string literal can be created, or any code can be commented, without escaping the contents: you just choose a long bracket with a number of equals signs such that the ending delimiter doesn't occur inside the string.

**Are there any other languages with infinitely extensible string delimiters?** I know about Perl's q-style, but that is AFAIK limited to single characters: `q#...#`, `qx...x`, etc. **I'm especially interested in solutions which, like Lua's, go beyond single-character delimiters.**

(For the curious: this question bubbled up when I tried to ssh multiple commands with `ssh 'multiple; commands'`, where one of those commands was a call to `sudo sh -c '...'`. I think shell is the only environment where I frequently manually create string literals with multiple levels of quoting.)

---

For those who want to know more about Lua's long brackets:

- The [Lua 5.3 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.1) (search for 'long bracket')
- Examples at [Lua wiki strings tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringsTutorial) (search for 'nesting quotes')
- Example at [Well House Consulting](http://www.wellho.net/resources/ex.php4?item=u104/mlx) (also contains a multiline comment example)

A valid Lua comment, and a valid Lua string:

```lua
--[[ This comments out an assignment to my_lua_string
my_lua_string = [==[one [=[inner]=] two]==] 
]]

-- This is a string delimited with long brackets
[=[one ]] two]=]
--> 'one ]] two'
```

Comment: Java allows this via `java.util.Scanner`. Too broad.

Comment: @EJP Reading the [`java.util.Scanner` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) it seems that is for parsing strings, not a syntactic construct to quote string literals. ['Too broad'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) does not seem to apply: " if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably too broad for our format." This question is about a clearly rare syntactic construct; it does not need a book, nor has it got many valid answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL allows this:  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/sql-syntax.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING

It is most-often used in defining stored procedures, like this (see the `$$`'s):

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment(i integer) RETURNS integer AS $myAddOne$
        BEGIN
                RETURN i + 1;
        END;
$myAddOne$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;`

However, I'm not aware of any others.

Answer (score 2):

The UNIX shell (and its derivatives), Perl, PHP and Ruby (at least) support [HEREDOCs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) where anything can be used as the delimiting TAG.